# Given an idea for an application, how should I decide which web technologies to use?

Tags: web-development, web-framework

Background:  I'm an experienced Java developer, know basic Javascript, HTML, and CSS (and find it easy to figure out how to do something), and have a little experience in Python.  I've seen Ruby before and edited a few lines of existing scripts.

I'm curious not so much about any given technology, but mainly about what my thought process should be when deciding which technologies to use.  Let's take a simple application - maybe an online address book where I can enter contact information, and create groups of contacts.  How should I go about evaluating the options that are out there?

The number of [frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks) out there  is daunting to say the least.  This should be a learning experience for me, but also I want the knowledge that I gain to be relevant, and I'm afraid of using something that I'll never use again.

Comment: Please check the [FAQ] - particularly what it has to say about "which language?" questions.

Comment: I realize that - I agree that it's questionable about whether this is an appropriate questions, but I'm not interested in particular recommendations.  Rather, *how* to decide what to use.  I'd categorize this as more of a "development methodology" question which seems to be allowed.

Comment: OK - but if it starts getting a lot of "use X" answers it's going to get closed.

Comment: i've decided to use RoR at work, for a minor project. And it was amazing, i learned a lot. But if you feel confortable with Java, go on! Many say it is unproductive, but no one beats JVM! And you have Grails at your disposal.

Comment: I'd go with a mix of 'use what you know best' and 'use what will get you a prototype quickly'. Since you're a Java programmer, go with a Java framework you know well, or the most popular one if you've not done web stuff before. Whilst there _are_ differences between various frameworks/languages, I see people get hung up on it too much, and their project has stalled as a result.

Answer (score 4):

1. What are you and your developer team already familiar with?  Are you comfortable using it?
2. How mature is the technology?  Is it a widely recognized and used technology, or is it at the fringes?
3. How productive are you in the technology?  Does it take days to implement the simplest of things?
4. Does the technology meet your customer requirements?

If this is just a personal project, the decision will most likely hinge on whether or not you want to learn something new.